# Why my implementation of linked list quick sort is much slower than array one?

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, sorting, quicksort

I been algorithm problem that requires me to do implementation of quick sort algorithm for linked list and array.
I have done both parts , algorithms are working, but it seems there is some bug in my quick-sort linked list implementation.

Here is my Quick sort linked list implementation.

```
public static void SortLinkedList(DataList items, DataList.Node low, DataList.Node high) 
    {
        if( low != null && low !=high)
        {
            DataList.Node p = _PartitionLinkedList(items, low, high);
            SortLinkedList(items, low, p);
            SortLinkedList(items, p.Next(), null);
        }


    }

    private static DataList.Node _PartitionLinkedList(DataList items, DataList.Node low, DataList.Node high) 
    {
        DataList.Node pivot = low;
        DataList.Node i = low;
        for (DataList.Node j = i.Next(); j != high; j=j.Next())
        {
            if (j.Value().CompareTo(pivot.Value()) <= 0)
            {

                items.Swap(i.Next(),j);
                i = i.Next();

            }
        }
        items.Swap(pivot, i);
        return i;
    }
```

Here is Quick Sort array implementation

```
 public static void SortData(DataArray items, int low, int high) 
    {
        if (low < high)
        {
            int pi = _PartitionData(items, low, high);
            SortData(items, low, pi - 1);
            SortData(items, pi + 1, high);
        }

    }
 static int _PartitionData(DataArray arr, int low, int high) 
    {
        double pivot = arr[high];
        int i = (low - 1);
        for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j].CompareTo(pivot)<=0)
            {
                i++;
                arr.Swap(i,j);
            }
        }
        arr.Swap(i + 1, high);
        return i + 1;
    }
```

Here is Quick sort array and linked list performance. (left n, right time)
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOUYb.png)
As you can see qs linked list took 10 min to sort 6400 elements. I dont think that its normal..

Also I dont think that its because of the data structure, because I was using same structure for selection sort and performance for both linked list and array were similar.

GitHub repo in case i forgot to provide some code. [Repo](https://github.com/arnas/tempalg)

Comment: It is okay for linked list implementation to be slower, since... what is random element access time for an array and a linked list in the Big-O notation? "and performance for both linked list and array were similar" --- this should be a worrying sign, since they cannot be. In any case - profile your code. Profiler is what tells you why something is slow.

Comment: So you think that its normal that linked list implementation is so much slower. For linked list it takes over 10 minutes , for array not even a sec.

Comment: "So you think that its normal that linked list implementation is so much slower." --- to answer that you need to make an analysis of your code. In terms of Big-O what is the complexity of your implementation of both linked list and array-based examples? Then, again - profiler.

Comment: @InvGhostt Think about it - an array takes the same amount of time to get an item from any index - O(1), whereas a linked list takes O(n), since it has to scan every single item. That will have a big impact on the complexity of your sorting function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 minutes is a very long time for 6400 elements.  It would normally require 2 or 3 horrible mistakes, not just one.

Unfortunately, I only see one horrible mistake:  Your second recursive call to `SortLinkedList(items, p.Next(), null);` goes all the way to the end of the list.  You meant for it to stop at `high`.

That might account for the 10 minutes, but it seems a little unlikely.

It also looks to me like your sort is incorrect, even after you fix the above bug -- be sure to test the output!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your linked list, particularly the swap method. Unless we see the implementation of the linked list, I think the problem area is there.

Is there a reason why you're using linked lists? They have o(n) search which makes quicksort n^2lg(n) sort.

A different way to do it is to add all the items in your linked lists to a list, sort that list, and recreate your linkedlist. List.Sort() uses quick sort.

```
public static void SortLinkedList(DataList items) 
{
    list<object> actualList = new list<object>();

    for (DataList.Node j = i.Next(); j != null; j=j.Next())
    {
        list.add(j.Value());
    }

    actualList.Sort();

    items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < actualList.Count;i++)
    {
        items.Add(actualList[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using linked list,because its requirement to use it and i cant make this workaround you are suggesting. Here is the implementation of the linked list  https://github.com/arnas/tempalg/blob/master/MyDataList.cs

Answer (score 0):

Quick sort for linked list is normally slightly different than quick sort for arrays. Use the first node's data value as the pivot value. Then the code creates 3 lists, one for values < pivot, one for values == pivot, one for values > pivot. It then does a recursive calls for the < pivot and > pivot lists. When the recursive call returns those 3 lists are now sorted, so the code only needs to concatenate the 3 lists.

To speed up concatenation of lists, keep track of a pointer to the last node. To simplify this, use circular lists, and use a pointer to the last node as the main way to access a list. This makes appending (joining) list simpler (no scanning). Once inside a function, use last->next in order to get a pointer to the first node of a list.

Two of the worst case data patterns are already sorted data or already reverse sorted data. If the circular list with pointer to last node method is used, then the average of last and first nodes could be used as a median of 2 which could help (note the list for nodes == pivot could end up empty).

Worst case time complexity is O(n^2). Worst case stack usage is O(n). The stack usage could be reduced by using recursion on the smaller of the list < pivot and list > pivot. After return, the now sorted smaller list would be concatenated with the list == pivot and saved in a 4th list. Then the sort process would iterate on the remaining unsorted list, then merging (or perhaps joining) with the saved list.

Sorting a linked list, using any method, including [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) , will be slower than moving the linked list to an array, sorting the array, then creating a linked list from the sorted array. However the quick sort method I describe will be much faster than using an array oriented algorithm with a linked list.